What’s the best way to mount an exterior light through a rim joist?
I’ve got a basement door directly under a rim joist, there’s a 10” piece of exterior trim directly on the joist. I want to mount a light above the door but have the fixture flush with the wall. I don’t want any type of box behind the fixture on the outside of the joist.
I’m getting the larger basement project inspected, I don’t want this to become an issue. Obviously every local building code is different but I’m curious if anyone knows the standard here.
My current plan is to install a 4” square metal box on the interior side of the rim joist, punch the center hole out and then drill that same hole location through the joist. That way my fixture can mount to the 10” trim and joist but the wire connections are all on the inside of the wall.
Anyone see any issues with this approach?

Sounds fine to me, as long as the box remains accessible from the inside of the house—will it?

Pictures? Also, a pancake might work even better than a four-square box.
